# how to parse the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, lxml.html

the following code parses the string.

```
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring("""<html>
 <body>
   <span class="simple_text">One</span> tehfghhxt</br>
   <span class="cyrillic_text">Второй</span> cyrcyrcyr</br>
 </body>
</html>
""")

txt1 = doc.xpath('/html/body/span[@class="simple_text"]/text()[1]')
print(txt1)
```

I would like to know how to parse the file that contains the same string. and which is in the same directory. please tell me.

Comment: The question is quite clear in the sense what can be expected from a beginner. The answer is explicitly shown in the `lxml` doc here http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html. The `StringIO()` is the way how to make a string act as an open file. You can just pass the open file object to the `parse()` function. It is likely that it even accepts the name of the file and it opens it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = open('file_with_string.html', 'r').read()
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(string)
```